# What is the distance in the matchit output?

Tags: r, matching

Does anybody know what is the `distance` in the output of `matchit()`?
Distance between what and what?

Comment: Maybe this helps (from the documentation): https://r.iq.harvard.edu/docs/matchit/2.4-20/Additional_Arguments_f.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I have read that. It does not explain it is distance between what and what!
I have one treat unit and 3 control units matched to it, and each one has a distance associated with it. So, it cannot be the distance between the treated and control units.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's the distance metric used for matching. The difference between the distance metrics for a pair of individuals is the distance between them. The default is the estimated propensity score for each unit. You can set the value of the distance using the `distance` option. You can also provide your own distance metric. For example, if you wanted to match on a different variable, such as age, you could create an `age` variable and set `distance = age`. For Mahalanobis distance matching, no individual receives a single distance metric because the distance between two units is computed using a formula, so none will be in the output.